# React native app build fails due to old version

Tags: android, node.js, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to build react native application that was developed in the old version. I am getting below error

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:lintVitalRelease'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find any version that matches com.facebook.react:react-native:0.12.+.
     Versions that do not match: 0.64.2
     Required by:
         project :app > project :react-native-vibration

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.7/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 38s
error Failed to build the app.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat build -x lint
    at makeError (D:\Projects\fox reactive native\FoxPharmaReact2\FoxPharmaReact\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\node_modules\execa\index.js:174:9)
    at Function.module.exports.sync (D:\Projects\fox reactive native\FoxPharmaReact2\FoxPharmaReact\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\node_modules\execa\index.js:338:15)
    at buildApk (D:\Projects\fox reactive native\FoxPharmaReact2\FoxPharmaReact\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\index.js:181:22)       
    at runOnSpecificDevice (D:\Projects\fox reactive native\FoxPharmaReact2\FoxPharmaReact\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\index.js:162:7)
    at buildAndRun (D:\Projects\fox reactive native\FoxPharmaReact2\FoxPharmaReact\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\index.js:147:12)    
    at D:\Projects\fox reactive native\FoxPharmaReact2\FoxPharmaReact\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\index.js:132:12
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async Command.handleAction (D:\Projects\fox reactive native\FoxPharmaReact2\FoxPharmaReact\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js:186:9)
```

I am trying to build and run React native application but getting the error mentioned in above description

Comment: Try updating your Gradle or React Native version. Have you tried that?

Comment: i have upgraded react native how to upgrade Gradle ?